# Merging matrix index in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset (x) contains

```
 1 10
20 30
34 38
59 83
...
```

I have a big matrix `nx1`. I want to assign a value 1 for each row in x. For example

```
mat[1:10,1] = 1 
mat[20:30,1] = 1
etc...
```

In R, the size of `x` is quite big and takes a while to do the following:

```
for ( j in 1:dim(x)[1] ) { 
    mat[x[j,1]:x[j,2], 1] <- 1 
}
```

Please help me if there is a faster way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily make a list of the rows you want to assign a value of 1 to in your big matrix, using `apply` on x with `seq.int` to get the row numbers like this...

```
rows <- unlist( apply( x , 1 , FUN = function(x){ seq.int(x[1],x[2])}) )
rows
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 34 35 36 37 38 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
```

And then use subsetting which will be much faster, like this

```
mat[ rows , 1 ] <- 1
```

Comment: Points for reading the question better than I did, and for demonstrating how to use indexing profitably.

Comment: +1 - an alternative for rows is `unlist(mapply(seq, x[,1], x[,2]))`.

Answer (score 1):

If `m` is your set of start and stop locations:

```
m <-  matrix(scan(), ncol=2)
#------
1: 1 10
3: 20 30
5: 34 38
7: 59 83
9: 
Read 8 items
mapply( seq.int,  m[,1], m[,2])

rx1[ unlist( mapply( seq.int,  m[,1], m[,2]) ), 1] <- 1
```

(Trivially different than SimonO101's earlier contribution.)

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` usually excels in cases like this.  Here is a `data.table`-based solution:

```
library(data.table)
indexes<-data.table(istart=c(1L,20L,34L,59L), istop=c(10L,30L,38L,83L))
mat<-data.table(val=sample(1L:1e5L,1e5))

mat[indexes[,list(i=seq(istart,istop)),by="istart"][,i],val:=1L]
```